# How can I call a php script from another file and display it on the current page?

Tags: php, echo, show, file-get-contents, readfile

I'm working on a custom contentlocker, where I display contents based on: Mobile/desktop platform, the operating system and the country of the user.

I'm stuck at the part where I want to show the content.
If a user from for example the US enter my site, it needs to show the webpage with different content then for example a user from CA should see.

So now we are at the part of the php script where the script determines this is a user from the US and it's gonna show us the webpage, with the US contents.
BUT
WITHOUT changing the url its currently on.
(so no redirect / header position: 'URL');)

It needs the show the detirmined contents on the same page.

How can I do this?

Can I echo the the contents from a php file ?
Can I use readfile?

I'm a bit lost here, it still needs to execute the scripts in the page like it would've if you visited the page by url.

Comment: include('filename.php')

Comment: [`include`](http://php.net/include]), [`require`](http://php.net/require)?

Comment: Thank you for the responses, will include still execute scripts in the file that you are including?

Comment: as include is a language construct the brackets are optional

Comment: yes, its the equivalent of copying the file contents directly in to the destination file

Comment: Thank you all! why is my question being downvoted? it was a sincere question

Comment: lack of research, put your question subject line in google, first hit (after the question) is the php include page

Answer (score 1):

You just dynamically create the include:

```
if ($inUS) {
   $include = 'us_users.php';
} else {
   $include = 'outside_us_users.php';
}

include($include);
```

for more countries just use a switch statement:

```
switch($country) {
   case "DE":
       $include = "de_users.php";
       beak;
   case "MX":
       $include = "mx_users.php";
       break;
   case "US": // US falls through to default
   default:
       $include = "us_users.php";
       break;   
}

include($include);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, how would I go about this with multiple countries?
US CA NZ AU etc
There will be a different $include everytime

Comment: how did you plan to determine where the visitor is from ?

Answer (score 1):

Set this in your page, at the beginning:

```
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
switch ($lang){
    case "fr":
        include('translate/index_fr.php');
        break;
    default:
        include('translate/index_en.php');
        break;
}

 echo $lg['test1'] . $lg['test2'];
```

**English file:** (`index_en.php`)

```
<?php

$lg = array(
'test' => 'Hello',
'test2' => 'World'
);


?>
```

**FR file** (`index_fr.php`)

```
<?php

$lg = array(
'test' => 'Bonjour',
'test2' => 'la terre'
);


?>
```

Comment: It's not for translating, but thanks!

Comment: Well so you also see how those arrays are used